# AWS Lambda: manual lifecycle management - I do not want termination after `return` in handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-multithreading

My handler python-function call another python-function in a new thread and return result on the next line - like this:

```
def aws_lambda_handler(event, context):
  threading.Thread(target=my_second_python_function).start()
  # thread for return without waiting

  return True  # this terminate Lambda with my second thread in process
```

I already have result for client and for speed I want to return it NOW without waiting a few seconds for finishing of the second python-function. But I found that AWS Lambda terminates after few milliseconds after `return` in the handler.

I can extract my second python-function to the new Lambda and call it before `return` but I think that this will little more expensive for money and time.

Maybe exists some way to not shutdown Lambda after `return` in handler? I tried long `timeout` but of course this is not for such case.

Comment: Maybe use `yield True` and only use `return` when the thread executing is finished?

Comment: @bluesummers interesting idea, I tried it - but Lambda can return only json-serializable things so I get `<generator object my-function at 0x7f619320c2b0> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Makes sense, interesting question though if you find a solution, please post it